# jquery ui how to create autocomplete with jquery ui with ajax response json

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, jquery-ui

I wanna ask how to create auto complete with json ajax response,
here is my code

```
$( "#employee" ).autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType:'json',
        url: SITE_URL + 'self_reimbursement/percobaan',
        success: function(data){
            response($.map(data, function(v,i){
                return {
                    label: v.employee_name,
                   };
            }));
        }
    });
    }
});
```

but it doesn't work, anyone know how to handle this?
the response showing data like this

```
[{"employee_name":"Lukas"},{"employee_name":"Yulianto Saparudin"},{"employee_name":"Lina"},{"employee_name":"Andre"}]
```

please help me

Comment: Can you share the link of autocomplete you are trying to implement?

Comment: I mean are you using any plugin to achieve autocompletion?

Comment: Oh, sorry I don't spot that here the url https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Take a look at this https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp. Sample code is given

Comment: Optimize your PHP code to directly return an one dimensional array `["Lukad","Yulianto","Lina"....]`.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois how to create array like that?

Comment: Depends on your PHP code :-)